# Custom message wrapping in the Ready to Install dialog

Tags: user-interface, internationalization, inno-setup

We have a custom installer for [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba) project which supports both per-user and per-machine installation. There are some ramifications for choosing one or other. For that reason, we insert a custom message at the Ready to Install page:
[image: Ready to Install image]

We also have support for localization with 4 languages. The biggest annoyance here is that the textarea in the dialog does not wrap text, meaning that if we don't insert a manual line break, it will run as one long line off the screen, requiring using the horizontal scrollbar.

We'd prefer to be able to automatically wrap the text so that we don't have to fiddle so much with inserting the manual line break for each localization. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What about rolling out your own custom page that behaves as you desire. Or, use the InfoAfterFile attribute and a RTF document.

Comment: Good question - we actually already have few custom page. It's more that we don't want to add yet another page and this page happen to have everything we have, save the wrapping of text. I suppose I could also suppress the page and substitute with my own but that's still more work for an already complex installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `WizardForm.ReadyMemo.WordWrap` to `True`. You must also set `WizardForm.ReadyMemo.ScrollBars` to `ssVertical`, for the `WordWrap` to take an effect.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ReadyMemo.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
  WizardForm.ReadyMemo.WordWrap := True;
end;

function UpdateReadyMemo(
  Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo,
  MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
  Result :=
    'Rubber duck Add-In will be available to all users.' + NewLine + NewLine +
    'NOTE: each user individually must register the Rubberduck Add-In ' +
      'as this is a per-user setting and cannot be deployed to all users.' + NewLine;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thanks!